# Error al crear usuario en SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Quiero crear un usuario nuevo,ya que acceso en sql mediante auntenticacion de windows pero como mi app la instalare en diferentes maquinas dentro de la misma red creare un usuario pero me marca un error en este signo "-" como lo puedo corregir

```
    Use Master Create user NombreUsuario from Login DESKTOP-FJ6785\PLC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás utilizando caracteres como - y /, lo correcto seria:

```
 Use Master Create user [NombreUsuario] from Login [DESKTOP-FJ6785\PLC]
```

Answer (score 0):

El sitio en Microsoft hay documentación al respecto

intenta usa comillas o ponlo entre []

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Por favor considera leer [answer]